# What does register and bus size depend on?

Tags: bus, register, multiplier

So here is a hardware sequential multiplier depicted. Number A is 51 bits width, number B is 48 bits width. I have to choose the most efficient size of buses and registers (optimize according to memory usage).

[image: general multiplier structure]

My actual question is: what do these sizes depend on? How should I proceed in this task? I am not looking for exact solution, but at least a hint, because I have no idea where to begin my search for information.

Comment: Don't they depend on things physically etched into semi conductors? Or do you mean "what size of number fits in a 51 bit register"?

Comment: @GradyPlayer : It's not the register that is 51 bit, but the fist multiplicand. And yes, here I don't consider any physical properties.

Comment: Well how many bits do you need to hold 2^51 * 2^48

Comment: Aha. So all I have to do in order to find the register sizes is calculate the worst possible size of the product? But what about buses then?

Comment: Doesn't need to be bigger than log2 max value+ any control bits you may have, but ints don't typically have any

Comment: I don't see any bus leading from B to ALU. The only bus is from B to control logic. This, and the fact that there are "shift" signals on the diagram, suggests that it is an iterative multiplication. We can try to guess what algorithm is employed here, but I'm not a big fan of guesswork. Please provide additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though the design is supposed to perform a 48x51-bit multiply in 48 steps, with each step either adding the "A" register to the product register or not.  It also appears to shift the "A" register, which isn't necessary.  If you want to load the B register, start the machine, and then have a result ready to be read, your product register needs to be large enough to hold the entire product (the sum of the two multiplcands' lengths); the adder will have to be that same width if you shift "A" as you're going along.  If instead of shifting the "A" register, you have the product either compute (Product >> 1) or (Product >> 1)+(A << 47) as bits shift out from the "B" register, then the adder only needs to add two 51-bit numbers for a 52-bit result.

Note also that for a small increase in complexity, you can double the speed of your multiplier by having the ALU choose among five operations on each step: (Product >> 2), (Product >> 2)+(A << 46), (Product >> 2)+(A << 47), (Product >> 2)-(A << 46), or (Product >> 2)-(A << 47).  Look up "Booth's Algorithm" for more information.

Comment: Thanks for an answer =) I asked this question quite a while ago, and it was an exam question. Of course I have already understood it, but thanks anyway =)

Answer (score 0):

well I think these are general purpose inbuilt multipliers in FPGA (DSP blocks) or other heterogeneous devices. In that case the size of registers are general purpose. It depends on your application, you can choose required number of bits. You can have 32bit multiplier out of this inbuilt multiplier. Thus depending upon your requirement u can fix the data bus.